# How to use sort_index() on a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I loaded  JSON file in to a dataframe using spark SQLContext.
It stores tweets from different users. It looks like below. I am using pandas library in python to explore the data in this dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
tweets = pd.read_json('/filepath')
sqlcontext = SQLContext(sc)
tweet_sdf = sqlcontext.createDataFrame(tweets)

tweet_sdf.show(10)
+-------------+------------------+-------------+--------------------+-------------------+
|      country|                id|        place|                text|               user|
+-------------+------------------+-------------+--------------------+-------------------+
|        India|572692378957430784|       Orissa|@always_nidhi @Yo...|    Srkian_nishu :)|
|United States|572575240615796736|    Manhattan|@OnlyDancers Bell...| TagineDiningGlobal|
|United States|572575243883036672|    Claremont|1/ "Without the a...|        Daniel Beer|
|United States|572575252020109312|       Vienna|idk why people ha...|   someone actually|
|United States|572575274539356160|       Boston|Taste of Iceland!...|     BostonAttitude|
|United States|572647819401670656|      Suwanee|Know what you don...|Collin A. Zimmerman|
|    Indonesia|572647831053312000|  Mario Riawa|Serasi ade haha @...|   Rinie Syamsuddin|
|    Indonesia|572647839521767424|Bogor Selatan|Akhirnya bisa jug...|       Vinny Sylvia|
|United States|572647841220337664|      Norwalk|@BeezyDH_ it's li...|                Cas|
|United States|572647842277396480|       Santee| obsessed with music|               kimo|
+-------------+------------------+-------------+--------------------+-------------------+
only showing top 10 rows

tweet_sdf.printSchema()

root
 |-- country: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- place: string (nullable = true)
 |-- text: string (nullable = true)
 |-- user: string (nullable = true)
```

I am trying to sort the dataframe on index 'id' using below.

```
tweet_sdf.sort_index(by='id', ascending=False, inplace=True)
```

But I receive an attribute error which is mentioned below.
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sort_index'

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-106-6cd99444a12a> in <module>()
----> 1 tweet_sdf.sort_index(by='id', ascending=False, inplace=True)

/home/notebook/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.pyc in __getattr__(self, name)
    837         if name not in self.columns:
    838             raise AttributeError(
--> 839                 "'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (self.__class__.__name__, name))
    840         jc = self._jdf.apply(name)
    841         return Column(jc)

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sort_index'
```

Version on pandas is 0.18.0 and python version is 2.7.11
Can someone help me understand why this is behaving in this way?

Comment: what is the type of `tweet_sdf`?

Comment: It is of type "pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame"

Comment: Try using only `sort` instead of `sort_index` then

Comment: Thank you. That worked. Does it mean that all the methods that can be used on a dataframe cannot be used on dataframe that is created using sqlcontext? Any reference will be of great help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Changes to sorting API](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-sorting-api)

[DataFrame.sort_index API reference](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html)

I believe the "by" argument has been removed after 0.17.0.  You probably need to change the argument or use sort.

> The by argument of DataFrame.sort_index() has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), because you need sort by column `id`.

```
print tweet_sdf
         country                  id          place                 text  \
0          India  572692378957430784         Orissa     @always_nidhi@Yo   
1  United States  572575240615796736      Manhattan    @OnlyDancers Bell   
2  United States  572575243883036672      Claremont    1/ "Without the a   
3  United States  572575252020109312         Vienna    idk why people ha   
4  United States  572575274539356160         Boston    Taste of Iceland!   
5  United States  572647819401670656        Suwanee    Know what you don   
6      Indonesia  572647831053312000    Mario Riawa    Serasi ade haha @   
7      Indonesia  572647839521767424  Bogor Selatan    Akhirnya bisa jug   
8  United States  572647841220337664        Norwalk    @BeezyDH_ it's li   
9  United States  572647842277396480         Santee  obsessed with music   

                 user  
0     Srkian_nishu :)  
1  TagineDiningGlobal  
2         Daniel Beer  
3    someone actually  
4      BostonAttitude  
5  Collin A Zimmerman  
6    Rinie Syamsuddin  
7        Vinny Sylvia  
8                 Cas  
9                kimo
```

```
tweet_sdf.sort_values(by='id', ascending=False, inplace=True)
print tweet_sdf
         country                  id          place                 text  \
0          India  572692378957430784         Orissa     @always_nidhi@Yo   
9  United States  572647842277396480         Santee  obsessed with music   
8  United States  572647841220337664        Norwalk    @BeezyDH_ it's li   
7      Indonesia  572647839521767424  Bogor Selatan    Akhirnya bisa jug   
6      Indonesia  572647831053312000    Mario Riawa    Serasi ade haha @   
5  United States  572647819401670656        Suwanee    Know what you don   
4  United States  572575274539356160         Boston    Taste of Iceland!   
3  United States  572575252020109312         Vienna    idk why people ha   
2  United States  572575243883036672      Claremont    1/ "Without the a   
1  United States  572575240615796736      Manhattan    @OnlyDancers Bell   

                 user  
0     Srkian_nishu :)  
9                kimo  
8                 Cas  
7        Vinny Sylvia  
6    Rinie Syamsuddin  
5  Collin A Zimmerman  
4      BostonAttitude  
3    someone actually  
2         Daniel Beer  
1  TagineDiningGlobal
```